# High Frequency run a script on another server

Tags: ssh

In my application I have two servers (private and external) and there is a need for the private server to run a script on the external server.

Using ssh, I am trying to test the limits of how many connections it will hold:

```
while (1)
  foreach k (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 )
    ssh -i /path/to/key user@host "ls;sleep 0.3" &
    sleep 0.06  # <=16.6 times/sec
  end
end
```

The external server (2 core CPU, 4 GB ram), manage to maintain the incoming connections when they are at a rate of about 16/sec. Anything faster than that, it has connection issues, and cpu load gets of the roof (total tasks & zombie processes amount start to accumulate. However memory usage seems low).

The error message that we see on the private server after a few seconds of high frequency connections is

```
 ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

running the same test script on the external server, we don't see an issue with that rate (cpu load is about 7%, no zombies).

Assuming it is a ssh issue, so we added these in the ssh config file and restarted the ssh service but it didn't help:

```
MaxStartups 20:50:100
MaxSessions 100
```

## UPDATE

As suggested, I tried to use ControlMaster. Here is what I did:

Added this to the ~/.ssh/config in the private server:

```
Host <external_host_ip>
       ControlMaster auto
       ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p
       ControlPersist 600
```

Created the first connection:

```
 ssh -M -S /home/user/.ssh/cm_socket/user@host_ip:22 -i ~/key.pem  user@host_ip
```

I checked, and something happened in the 'cm_socket' folder:

```
$ ll ~/.ssh/cm_socket/
srw------- 1 user user    0 Oct 18 18:10 user@host_ip:22=
```

but when I tried to do a subsequent ssh without the key, it didn't work:

```
$ ssh -M -S /home/user/.ssh/cm_socket/user@host_ip:22 user@host_ip
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is there a way to increase the throughput that can be handled by this setup?

Comment: Use `ControlMaster` functionality of client OpenSSH.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried, for some reason it didn't work. I updated the question with the result, I would be glad if you can take a look

Comment: Using `-M` prevents the second connection to connect to the existing socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ControlMaster`:

```
Host <external_host_ip>
   ControlMaster auto
   ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p
   ControlPersist 600
   User user
   IdentityFile ~/key.pem
```

And then connect just using `ssh host_ip`. The first session initiates the connection, the others (up to 100 consecutive according to your setup) will reuse the first one. It should get a lot faster.

Comment: excellent. It worked! Since I don't want the connection to close, I am using ControlPersist=yes. This ssh tunnel must always be kept open. I have read about 'autossh'. Just to be sure, is there a need for 'autossh' here, or is the ControlMaster solution good enough?

Comment: `autossh` re-establishes the connection in case of failure (for tunnels). For normal connection, you don't need that. Also some `ServerAliveTimeout` and `ServerAliveInterval` will make the connection last in the times of inactivity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have another related issue [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/839107/using-controlmaster-with-user-www-data)

Comment: link to the issue => [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/839107/using-controlmaster-with-user-www-data) (was not very clear in previous comment)