# Using ControlMaster with user www-data

Tags: ssh, apache2

In my application I have two servers (private and external) and there is a need for the private server to run a script on the external server at a very high frequency.

To allow this high frequency throughput, I am using `ControlMaster` to open a persistent ssh connection (without it the external server crashes because of high cpu load as a result of dealing with the authentication).

This is the ssh configuration:

```
Host <external_host_ip>
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 600
  User user1
  IdentityFile ~/key.pem
```

This configuration worked for 'user1' user. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me for the 'www-data' user.

Assuming that the root folder for www-data is /var/www, I added the folder cm_socket there, and when I test the connection, I see that something happens there:

```
$ ll /var/www/.ssh/cm_socket/
srw------- 1 www-data www-data    0 Oct 19 08:49 user1@host_ip:22=
```

However, it caused apache to crash, and the only thing that help was restarting apache.

## UPDATE

/var/www should be the root of www-data:

```
 $ cat /etc/passwd | grep www
 www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

This is the /var/www/.ssh/config:

```
Host <external_host_ip>
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist yes
    User user1
    IdentityFile /home/user1/key_wwwdata.pem
```

content and permissions of /var/www/.ssh:

```
$ ll /var/www/.ssh/
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 19 08:49 cm_socket/
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  198 Oct 19 08:44 config
```

permission of the key file:

```
$ ll /home/user1/key_wwwdata.pem
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 1675 Oct 18 09:11 /home/user1/key_wwwdata.pem
```

Is there a way to make this solution work for all users (including www-data)?

Comment: Different user have different home directory and different place for configuration. Do you have the key (`key.pem`) in his home directory with proper permissions?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated the question with the configuration I have for the www-data user, would appreciate if you can take a look (I know that the location of the key_wwwdata.pem is in the file system of user1, but it should have permissions. Could that be the issue? I am a little afraid to try, since it crashed the apache last time I tested

Comment: Well, this is not a good idea. User `www-data` will not have access to the home directory of the user `user1` and if it does, it is plain wrong and `ssh` will not allow you to use this key. The apache was most probably not crashed, but only hanging in password prompt.

Comment: I understand the security issue. What would you suggest me to do? I need to run a high frequency script on the external server initiated by a button click in the browser

Comment: do you mean that if key_wwwdata.pem would be in /var/www with permission to www-data (same permissions as now), there would be no password prompt and the tunnel will work?

Comment: I can only guess, post a verbose log from the process under www-data. Use `-vvv` switches and direct the output to some file: `&> /tmp/verbose_log` and add it to the question.

Comment: I solved my problem with visudo, giving www-data permission to sudo a specific script

Answer (score 1):

The **`www-data`** user's shell is usually set to `/usr/sbin/nologin` which would prevent ssh logins.

You could try changing **`www-data`**'s shell by running:

```
sudo chsh www-data
```

And entering `/bin/bash` as the new shell value.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip. I needed to do `composer update` using the root account. Composer warns you for updating as root for obvious reasons. So @Weboide's method is very useful. Additional step after `chsh www-data` was `su www-data`. Then ran `composer update` and `exit` to get back to root.